# Where can I find tools for reverse engineering Lua

Tags: disassembly, tools, decompile, byte-code

Since `Lua` is an interpreted/compiled language that its own compilers and isn't usually translated/compiled with a C compiler. What tools should be used to reverse engineer an application written in `Lua`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your application is compiled to a binary you might still be able to use normal debuggers like IDA. However, Lua has its own tools for decompiling from machine code and byte code. These links should be kept up to date by the Lua community.

**Lua Wiki:** [LuaTools](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools)

If you need support for Lua 5.2 [LuaAssemblyTools](https://github.com/mlnlover11/LuaAssemblyTools) is the first to support that.

Comment: I'm [trying to introduce new built-in functions](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14091/hacking-lua-introduce-new-functions-into-built-lua) to a game that comes packed with a custom Lua implementation. Do you have any ideas what I can do this? The game is Supreme Commander.