# Help decrypt lua base64

Tags: script

Anyone knows how to decrypt this lua script ?
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PewPewPew2/BoL/master/DancingShoes.lua

Answer (score 3):

That's simple a some Lua bytecode (version 5.2) stored as base64. Use `base64 -d` to decode it, and then check the binary file generated using `file`:

```
$ file DancingShoes.bin
DancingShoes.bin: Lua bytecode, version 5.2
```

Comment: i need to see the source code

Comment: @maxstreiker: See http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2050/1562